# Can not refresh not managed object

Tags: java, jpa

I've to refresh a list of `Eleve` from the database to a Jtable. 
The `Jtable` it's self is bound to an observable `list< Eleve >`, so any add/delete to the list is automatically updated in the `Jtable`.

My code explain it's self:

```
EleveJpaController ejc = new EleveJpaController(emf);
java.util.Collection<Eleve> data = ejc.findEleveByNiveauClasseNomPrenom(niv, classe, nom, prenom);

for (Eleve entity : data) {
    entityManager.refresh(entity);
}

list.clear();
list.addAll(data);
```

List< Eleve > findEleveByNiveauClasseNomPrenom(a,v,x,n):

```
 public List<Eleve> findEleveByNiveauClasseNomPrenom(String niv,String classe,String nom, String prenom)
    {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        Query qr= em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Eleve e WHERE e.niv.niv like '%"+niv+"%' and e.class1.libelle like '%"+classe+"%' and e.nom like '%"+nom+"%' and e.prenom like '%"+prenom+"%'");

       return qr.getResultList(); 
    }
```

As you can see, It's well manged list of `Eleve` objects.. So why this exception is thrown ?

```
[EL Info]: 2013-12-02 13:25:33.312--ServerSession(1903253526)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504
[EL Info]: 2013-12-02 13:25:35.005--ServerSession(1903253526)--file:/C:/Users/marwen/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JocondeFinale/build/classes/_JocondeFinalePU login successful
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not refresh not managed object: entities.Eleve[ idEleve=7 ].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.refresh(EntityManagerImpl.java:943)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.refresh(EntityManagerImpl.java:849)
    at entities.GestionPaiement.niveauJcbbxItemStateChanged(GestionPaiement.java:736)
    at entities.GestionPaiement.access$2000(GestionPaiement.java:32)
    at entities.GestionPaiement$FormListener.itemStateChanged(GestionPaiement.java:607)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1225)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(JComboBox.java:1273)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1329)
    at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(AbstractListModel.java:118)
    at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:94)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:578)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:624)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicComboPopup.java:835)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(BasicComboPopup.java:499)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Cheers.

Comment: you may try begin transaction and end transaction. end of the transaction commit()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably using a different EntityManager to refresh your entities than the one which loads the entities from the database. The entities are not managed in the new EntityManager. According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29), the exception is the normal behaviour for not managed entities. Either use the same EntityManager, or use [merge()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29) to make your objects managed

Comment: to be clear, it *is* recommended to use different EntityManagers for different Actions. But i think in this case it would be plausible to use one

Answer (score 4):

That means that when calling `entityManager.refresh(entity)`, your entities are not managed by *that instance* of `EntityManager`, not by the entityManager used in `findEleveByNiveauClasseNomPrenom()`. On the other side, you may ask yourself why you try to refresh those entities (havbe you made any changes to them?).

Answer (score 0):

As @Simiil says, `merge` can get an entity bean managed.

```
@Transactional
public void refresh(Entity entity) {
    final Entity e = getFacade().getEntityManager().merge(entity).;
    getFacade().getEntityManager().refresh(e); // you cannot use $entity because you need to use the brand new managed entity 
}
```